# overlapping two diagrams by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the following script to create two diagrams by ggplot2 in R:

```
library(ggplot2)
coin <- read.csv("D:/RStudio/data/coin_test.csv", header = TRUE)
ggplot(data.frame (x=coin$Order, y=coin$Sn), aes(x=x, ymax=y, ymin=0))+geom_linerange()+xlab("order")
ggplot(data.frame (x=coin$Order, y=coin$Pb), aes(x=x, ymax=y, ymin=0))+geom_linerange(xlab="order",col="red")+xlab("order")
```

The two graphs look like these, and each line represents a single value with a unique order:

[image: Sn_test]
[image: Pb_test]

I want to overlap these two diagrams so they share the same x and y axis in the same order. Can anyone enlighten me how to do this?

Comment: Please add a MWE after reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Put them both in one data.frame, and use two `geom_linerange` layers with different `aes` mappings for `y`. Or melt your data and color by variable.

Comment: Thanks. I use melt function and plot the data like regular bar charts and it works.